# Editing ArcSDE feature online through web app

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, editing, web

I am working on building a web app where I would have a feature class from our ArcSDE. I want anyone in my organization to edit that feature class and want the changes to reflect on our ArcSDE too.

Comment: Note that the product "ArcSDE" no longer exists. The term of art for the past ten years has been "enterprise geodatabase".